# Swapping data in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, compare, points, twitch

I made Twitch bot for points and i need now !top10 command,i made it to read my points.ini file and if contains channelName that i use to store number of points and usernames in usernamesTop10 and pointsTop10 arrays.

I need now to cycle trough whole document and compare points and then swap points and username if newUser has more points.

These are steps:

> 1) get first username in file.
>   2) get points of that user.
>   3) record  both in respective arrays.
>   4) get next username.
>   5) get points of that user.
>   6) compare points vs entire array and insert at point where they
>    have more points than the last person and fewer points than the next
>    person Repeat steps 4 to 6 until end of file

Here is code : http://pastebin.com/PztMj9Nw (I couldn't past it here, dunno why)

It's not finished, so please, could you help me with it? I'm not that smart i guess...

Thanks in advance, i appreciate any help!

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour] it will make you smarter at least as to how SO works

Comment: Why do you use a text file to save score?I think json will be much better.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some help from a design standpoint might help.

I'm assuming you are storing your current top 10 in some array?

If so you should access this top 10 array and find the user with the lowest points. Keep track of this value. Lets say we call this variable 'threshold'.

- To update your top 10, loop through your file calling GetPoints on every user. If you find a user with points > threshold, kick the lowest user out of the top10 and replace them with this new user. Be sure to update your new threshold value.
- Repeat this until you can no longer find any users with more points than your threshold.
- Additionally, if you want to keep your top 10 in order you can implement a simple sort algorithm.

Comment: yup i'm storing in string usernamesTop10 & int pointsTop10 arrays, and how  could i kick lowest user out of top10?